# How to use provideRouteAlternatives=true in google maps api?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps-api-3

Currently I get the distance between 2 places in my c# winforms application by doing this :

```
string requesturl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin + "&destination=" + destination + "&sensor=false;
string content = fileGetContents(requesturl);

JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
distance = (decimal)o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].distance.value") / 1000;

private static string fileGetContents(string fileName)
{
    string sContents = string.Empty;
    string me = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("http:") > -1)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName);
            sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
        }
        else
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
            sContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
    catch { sContents = "unable to connect to server "; }
    return sContents;
}
```

This works very well but it always returns the fastest route, not the shortest.

I would like to get the shortest distance, so I want to add `provideRouteAlternatives=true` to the call to google api. Then I could search in the file in each route to get the shortest.
But how do I do that ?
Just to be clear, if more than one route would be returned I know how to adapt my code to search in each route, the question is how to get this parameter to start working so more than one route is returned.

I tried this :

```
string requesturl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" 
    + origin + "&destination=" 
    + destination + "&sensor=false&provideRouteAlternatives=true";
```

but it does not seems to do anything.
When I ask google for directions with the same adresses I do get more than one route, but this api does not.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible like this ?
Maybe I need javascript or something, is that possible in winforms ?
An example would be so nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, I was using the wrong parameter.
I have to use alternatives=true in stead of provideroutealternatives=true

EDIT
I discovered this by chance when I was trying different things and at one time I just tried `alternatives` in stead of `provideroutealternatives` and to my surprise it worked and still is working. The documentation still writes provideroutealternatives and that parameter still is not working. So my guess it that there is some miscommunication between the developers and the document writers at google.

**EDIT**

@MrEduar pointed out to me that I was reading the wrong documentation.
`provideRouteAlternatives` is for the [javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) library,
`alternatives` is for the [directions api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions).

So the documentation is correct after all, you just need to be carefull to use the correct documentation. It's easy to make a mistake there.

Comment: I have just been messing around with this problem for the last two hours. Thank you for the solution! (BTW, the Google docs still list "provideRouteAlternatives" as the parameter name.)

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe at Google they should google some more about problems with their documenation :)

Comment: No information where I get your solution because in the documentation of the google maps api there is nothing related to your magic parameter. Also, I just tried it and it is not a valid solution as of today.

Comment: @MrEduar I just tried it and it still works with me. Does this give an error or something for you ?

Comment: @MrEduar I tried with this url `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=1190 Belgium&destination=3832JP Holland&sensor=false&alternatives=true&key=YourKeyHere` and it worked like a charm

Comment: You need to edit your answer, and say where you got the answer, if it was in an official google documentation or somewhere else in the forum.

Comment: @MrEduar It was some time ago, what I remember is that I was trying different things and at one time I just tried it with `alternatives` in stead of `provideroutealternatives` and to my surprise that worked, and still is working. The documentation still writes provideroutealternatives and that parameter still is not working. So my guess it that there is some miscommunication between the developers and the document writers at google. So I did not got this answer from somewhere, I stumbled on it myself. I have also put this in the answer, as you requested

Comment: The problem is that you are reading the wrong documentation.
`provideRouteAlternatives` is for the [javascript library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), while `alternatives` is for the [directions api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions).